# azure logic app retry when job already running

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have an azure webjob that needs to be called every 5 mins with the argument "IsFullImport=false", and every Saturday at 12am with argument "IsFullImport=true". Currently I have 2 Logic Apps with reoccurrence set up that point to the same webjob, 1 runs every 5 mins and the other every Saturday at 12am.

The problem is if the every 5 min Logic App is running at the same time the Saturday at 12am one runs, I'll get a 409 error saying "conflict the WebJob is already running". Once the 12am one errors it won't try again until the next Saturday. I looked into retry policy and it doesn't apply to error 409. I also looked into concurrency policy and it seems that only applies to instances of the same Logic App, not 2 different Logic Apps. Is there a way I can get the Saturday 12am Logic App to retry if webjob is already running or maybe have one Logic App with 2 different schedules and api call?

Examples of Api calls:

Called Every 5 Mins:

[https://mysite.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/triggeredwebjobs/MyJob/run?arguments="IsFullImport=false"](https://mysite.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/triggeredwebjobs/MyJob/run?arguments=%22IsFullImport=false%22)

Called Every Saturday at 12am:
[https://mysite.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/triggeredwebjobs/MyJob/run?arguments="IsFullImport=true"](https://mysite.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/triggeredwebjobs/MyJob/run?arguments=%22IsFullImport=true%22)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this requirement, we can implement it in one logic app theoretically. But if we do it in one logic app, I think we need to deal with many problems about time around `Saturday 12am`. So I suggest you to do it in separate logic apps and provide a solution below for your reference:

**1.** In your recurrence every Saturday 12am logic app, initialize a variable named `statusCode` and set its value as `409`.

[image]

**2.** Then add "[Until](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-loops#until-loop)" loop in your logic app and set the condition as `statusCode` not equal to `409`.

[image]

**3.** In "**Until**" loop, add a "**HTTP**" action to request your api `https://mysite.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/triggeredwebjobs/MyJob/run?arguments="IsFullImport=true` and use "Set variable" action to set the value of `statusCode` as `outputs('HTTP')?['statusCode']`

[image]

**4.** **This step is critical**, click `...` button of "**Set variable**" action, then click "**Configure run after**".

[image]

Check both `is successful` and `has failed` options.
[image]

**5.** After that, your logic app will continue to request the api until the `statusCode` is not equal to `409`

Comment: What an awesome answer screenshots and all, really appreciate it, I'm going to give this a try now and see how it works, I'll let you know, thanks.

Comment: Thanks sir this does appear to be working, I kicked off the Every 5 min Logic App, then waited for it to start running, then kicked off this Saturday one and I see it was waiting for the other to finish before starting. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @Hurry Shen, one thing I'm noticing is it only seems to try 60 times before it moves on and still mark the setting of the variable as successful (and the overall Logic App run as successfull), but the HTTP task still failed. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Nevermind I found it, its the Until Limit count, upped that to the limit of 5000. Thanks.